How to customize android Listview UI
Here is my android Listview. I am trying to customize such as increase the row height,increasing cell padding and etc. How to get it done?
<ListView
android:id="@+id/listviewnew"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="670dp"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
android:background="#FDFBFB"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

My list view looks like this

I need to make it look beautiful.How to do it?

"To display a more custom view for each item in your dataset, implement a ListAdapter. For example, extend BaseAdapter and create and configure the view for each data item in getView(...)" says the Android developer documentation and that's the way to stylize the ListView items.
